# Connected to wifi, but no internet on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, network-manager

My new dell xps 13 haswell developer edition ( with ubuntu 12.04) began to have problems with the wifi.

Everything worked just fine till yesyerday when I connected my computer to wifi at work (it worked just fine) and come back home and connected to the usual wifi.

It seemed connected, but the internet didn't work. I have tryied a lot of solutions proposed on this site as, modifying the ilwifi.conf file by adding the command: `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1`.

It works just fine using the cable, and not at all usin wifi. I have installed wicd and the interface tells me that there are no wireless network found.

I have also desactivated the proxy in Mozilla, but still no success. I have also reinstalled the drivers for my wifi card, and again, no success.

Here are the results of some commands when the cable is not connected, that can be helpful:

```
cris@christi:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     no wireless extensions.

cris@christi:~$ ifconfig

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1344 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1344 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:129867 (129.8 KB)  TX bytes:129867 (129.8 KB)


wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5c:51:4f:ed:4e:73 
          inet addr:192.168.1.52  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5e51:4fff:feed:4e73/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:596 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:549 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:135170 (135.1 KB)  TX bytes:97869 (97.8 KB)

cris@christi:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [SFR_80F0] ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        5C:51:4F:ED:4E:73

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           1 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
......
  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.52
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

cris@christi:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for cris:
PCI (sysfs) 
  *-network              
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Wireless 7260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 6b
       serial: 5c:51:4f:ed:4e:73
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.5.0-45-generic firmware=22.0.6.0 ip=192.168.1.52 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes
       resources: irq:60 memory:f0400000-f0401fff


Jan 23 10:04:12 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info>   address 192.168.1.52
Jan 23 10:04:12 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info>   prefix 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jan 23 10:04:12 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info>   gateway 192.168.1.1
Jan 23 10:04:12 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info>   hostname 'christi'
Jan 23 10:04:12 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info>   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Jan 23 10:04:12 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Configure Commit) scheduled...
Jan 23 10:04:12 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) started...
Jan 23 10:04:13 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> (wlan0): writing resolv.conf to /sbin/resolvconf
Jan 23 10:04:13 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> (wlan0): device state change: ip-config -> activated (reason 'none') [70 100 0]
Jan 23 10:04:13 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> Activation (wlan0) successful, device activated.
Jan 23 10:04:13 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 5 of 5 (IPv4 Commit) complete.
Jan 23 10:04:13 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> wpa_supplicant die count reset
Jan 23 10:04:32 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> (wlan0): IP6 addrconf timed out or failed.
Jan 23 10:04:32 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) scheduled...
Jan 23 10:04:32 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) started...
Jan 23 10:04:32 christi NetworkManager[1074]: <info> Activation (wlan0) Stage 4 of 5 (IPv6 Configure Timeout) complete.


cris@christi:~$ dmesg | grep wlan | tail -n20 
[  921.672554] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  921.724628] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[  930.114041] wlan0: authenticate with 30:7e:cb:a1:80:f4
[  930.114910] wlan0: send auth to 30:7e:cb:a1:80:f4 (try 1/3)
[  930.118894] wlan0: authenticated
[  930.119243] wlan0: associate with 30:7e:cb:a1:80:f4 (try 1/3)
[  930.123517] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 30:7e:cb:a1:80:f4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[  930.124285] wlan0: associated
[  930.124801] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[ 1101.164462] wlan0: deauthenticating from 30:7e:cb:a1:80:f4 by local choice (reason=3)
[ 1101.196490] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1101.488712] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1101.548956] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 1109.942962] wlan0: authenticate with 30:7e:cb:a1:80:f4
[ 1109.943982] wlan0: send auth to 30:7e:cb:a1:80:f4 (try 1/3)
[ 1109.945787] wlan0: authenticated
[ 1109.949796] wlan0: associate with 30:7e:cb:a1:80:f4 (try 1/3)
[ 1109.952544] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 30:7e:cb:a1:80:f4 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
[ 1109.953463] wlan0: associated
[ 1109.955262] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Can anybody help me with this? Thank you

---

The result of dmesg | grep firmware is:

```
[    2.950585] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.0.6.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.002968] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[    3.119174] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[ 3863.176879] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[ 3863.312469] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[16997.271422] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-lts-quantal-3.5.0/drivers/base/firmware_class.c:597 request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0()
[16997.271471]  [<ffffffff81439f95>] request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0
[16997.271515] bluetooth hci0: firmware: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq will not be loaded
[16997.271517] Bluetooth: hci0 failed to open Intel firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq(-11)
[16997.271522] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-lts-quantal-3.5.0/drivers/base/firmware_class.c:597 request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0()
[16997.271564]  [<ffffffff81439f95>] request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0
[16997.271600] bluetooth hci0: firmware: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq will not be loaded
[35380.715329] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq
[35380.849609] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[59731.794863] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-lts-quantal-3.5.0/drivers/base/firmware_class.c:597 request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0()
[59731.794914]  [<ffffffff81439f95>] request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0
[59731.794961] bluetooth hci0: firmware: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq will not be loaded
[59731.794962] Bluetooth: hci0 failed to open Intel firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq(-11)
[59731.794967] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-lts-quantal-3.5.0/drivers/base/firmware_class.c:597 request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0()
[59731.795011]  [<ffffffff81439f95>] request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0
[59731.795047] bluetooth hci0: firmware: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq will not be loaded
[59742.687217] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-lts-quantal-3.5.0/drivers/base/firmware_class.c:597 request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0()
[59742.687278]  [<ffffffff81439f95>] request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0
[59742.687324] bluetooth hci0: firmware: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq will not be loaded
[59742.687326] Bluetooth: hci0 failed to open Intel firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.2.3.d.bseq(-11)
[59742.687331] WARNING: at /build/buildd/linux-lts-quantal-3.5.0/drivers/base/firmware_class.c:597 request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0()
[59742.687374]  [<ffffffff81439f95>] request_firmware+0xb5/0xf0
[59742.687410] bluetooth hci0: firmware: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.bseq will not be loaded
```

I also call Dell support for more information and they made me change the channel for the access point to wifi from automatic to 11, because they said it's more compatible with their wifi card. Now it's working. But sometimes it becomes really slow. On the other hand, when I connect it to wifi at work it works great.

---

```
dmesg | grep firmware command result:
dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.836895] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 60 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.143750] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode' failed.
[    3.143769] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[  206.231931] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 60 for MSI/MSI-X
[  206.234528] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode' failed.
[  206.234533] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[  416.621741] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 60 for MSI/MSI-X
[  416.625783] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.1.7.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[  416.636008] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[  416.636132] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[  416.636342] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[  416.844538] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[  416.857390] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
[  416.857596] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
cris@christi:/lib/firmware$ dmesg | grep firmware
[    3.143750] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode' failed.
[    3.143769] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[  206.234528] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode' failed.
[  206.234533] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[  416.625783] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.1.7.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the newer updated firmware file. With a working wired ethernet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
cd /lib/firmware
sudo mv iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode  iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.bak
sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
```

Unload and reload the driver so it sees and uses the newer firmware:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwldvm
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Detach the ethernet and your wireless should be working correctly.

If it still isn't working, check for informative clues:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

The oem-wireless-bluetooth package installs an earlier version of iwlwifi that requests 7260-6.ucode. The more stable version is 7260-7.ucode. While you have installed the newer firmware, the installed driver is still calling the older. Let's fix it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge oem-wireless-bluetooth-intel-7260-dkms*
```

Download this file to your desktop: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.12.8/backports-3.12.8-1.tar.xz  Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.12.8-1
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and let us hear your report.

Comment: I have observed that the wifi connection works at the office, but not at home. Sometimes when I deconnect and reconnect to home wifi it starts working for a while, even though is slow. I have the same problem with one of my other laptops. But the others work just fine. Can it be a driver incompatibility ? I have installed the drivers Dell certified for my laptop version:  [link](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails/Product/xps-13-9333?driverId=4NTWR&osCode=1204A&fileId=3322730329&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CS)-oem-wireless-bluetooth-intel-7260-dkms_3.10.20130828_amd64.

Comment: It appears that there is a whole array of packages in their package. Did you install every one of them? Does your other laptop use the same Intel 7260 wireless device? Perhaps it is a configuration issue in the router.

Comment: I have installed everything on my laptop. I don't think that my ancient laptop has the same 7260 wireless device. What is wired is that it worked well for one week. I don't know what happened. And for the other laptop it worked for almost an year. Only recently it stopped working.

Comment: If you have the trouble with two laptops with differing wireless cards, could it be a problem in the router?

Comment: But the other ones are working well (another dell and a hp). And also my smartphones works.I really don't know what else to do. Any idea?

Comment: I worked on and solved a case yesterday where we removed _entirely_ the Dell wireless driver and installed backports! Before I suggest this solution, please confirm: dmesg | grep firmware. If it is 22.0.6.0, I suspect it is at the heart of your problem and I will recommend a solution.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your comment. Indeed, it is 22.0.6.0. Here is the result of your command:

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: When I execute "sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi" it says FATAL module iwlwifi is in use. When I execute dmesg | grep iwl, I still have 20.0.6.0  firmware version.

Comment: Even after you compiled the newer version from backports and rebooted?

Comment: I've done all till the end of the comment and now i don't have the wifi anymore. I installed the backports lso. What should I do to have my wifi connection again?

Comment: Here is the result of dmsg: [    2.877285] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 61 for MSI/MSI-X
[    3.184651] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: request for firmware file 'iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode' failed.
[    3.184658] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!

Comment: That's why you have no wifi. Please repeat the firmware part above and reboot. You will need ethernet to wget the firmware.

Comment: When I do it I have this error: mv: cannot stat `iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode': No such file or directory

Comment: OK, skip that step and move to the next one.

Comment: Did all the other ones and still no wifi. It doesn't see any connection

Comment: Please show me: cd /lib/firmware && ls | grep 7260

Comment: iwlwifi-7260-6.ucode
iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.bak

Comment: The firmware is still not downloaded in the right place. With the terminal still in /lib/firmware and the ethernet still hooked up, please do: sudo wget https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/egrumbach/linux-firmware.git/plain/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode  And then check again: ls | grep 7260. Now you should see iwlwifi-7260-6.ucode iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.bak iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode.

Comment: And is your wireless stable and working as expected? If so, please accept my answer.

Comment: I tried to watch a video and I have the impression that it worked just fine. Please see my answer to see the result of the command: dmesg | grep firmware. Why does the message 'no suitable firmware found'? Thanks

Comment: Is that the message since you rebooted?

Comment: You're right, after reboot it's ok. Thank you for your help. I'll let you know if I'll have problems.

Comment: If you need to address the bluetooth firmware,I suggest a new question.

Comment: Yes, please. I have the impression that the bluetooth is disabled.

Comment: Please post a new question: http://askubuntu.com/questions